# Why does this Javascript match() function Crash My Browser?

Tags: javascript, regex, crash

#### WHAT I DO:

- Make sure Firebug is working.
- Put a break point in the isWrappedInParens() function.
- Navigate to my webapp.
- Trigger a call to isWrappedInParens().
- Step through isWrappedInParens(). Everything goes fine, but it does not proceed past the line of code indicated as the "CRASH POINT".
- I also tried it without Firebug running or having a break point, but it still freezes.

#### WHAT I NOTICE:

- In most cases, isWrappedInParens() works fine.
- When it does not work, Firefox freezes. I can still minimize/expand/close the window, though.
- I also noticed that when the test string is a bit shorter (less parentheses), firefox hangs but eventually finishes (~30 seconds) correctly.

#### EXAMPLE STRING THAT CRASHES FIREFOX

```
// Note that this is not wrapped in parentheses,
// since it is two separate sets of nested parentheses
var test = "(the OR (and) OR (and) OR (and)) AND ((to) OR (to) OR (to))";
```

#### BACKGROUND

- Browser: Firefox 3.6.18
- The webapp is a jetty application.

#### CODE

```
isWrappedInParens = function(str){
    if(_.isNull(str)) {
        return false;
    }
    str = str.trim();

    var pattern = /^[(](([(][^()]+[)]|[^()]+)|[(]([(][^()]+[)]|[^()]+)+[)])+[)]$/;

    var matchesPattern;
    try{
        matchesPattern = str.match(pattern) || null; //CRASH POINT!!!!!!!!!!!
    }catch(err){
        return false; //Note that no error is ever caught from freezing
    }

    var isWrapped = !_.isUndefined(matchesPattern) && !_.isNull(matchesPattern);
    return isWrapped;
}
```

#### WHERE THE REGEX CAME FROM:

```
// Atoms, building blocks for the expressions
var parenAtom = "[(][^()]+[)]";
var nonParenAtom = "[^()]+";

// Expressions, building blocks for the final regular expression
var baseCase = "(" + parenAtom + "|" + nonParenAtom + ")";
var nestedCase = "[(]_base_[)]"
    .replace("_base_", baseCase);

// Regular Expression
var wholeCase = "^[(](_base_|_nested_)+[)]$"
    .replace("_base_", baseCase)
    .replace("_nested_", nestedCase);
var pattern = new RegExp(wholeCase, "");
```

Comment: That regex and test string work fine for me in Firefox.  Of  course, I'm not using an antique version of the browser :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm required to use that version for my project. I'm not sure the inner-workings of match(), but I don't understand why it'd hang on a very finite string... I mean, it doesn't even throw an error or anything.

Comment: Well it's probably simply a browser bug.  The JavaScript engine in current (supported - the 3.6 release of Firefox is no longer supported) versions of the browser is quite a bit different.

Comment: Looking through the Firefox bug database, there have been many regular expression bugs found and categorized loosely as "exponential behavior" bugs.  Most of them have been fixed in the newer versions of the browser.

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks! Write that up as an answer, and I'll give you a green check.

Comment: not probably; definitely -- if the browser crashes, then it goes without saying that it's a browser bug.

Comment: You're probably better served with a simple state machine that goes once through all characters and matches parentheses. Write some unit tests and they should lead you to the path of righteousness ;)

Comment: I do not understand your RegExp pattern. If you're trying to match brackets, you should escape them twice (if using the RegExp constructor as you are) as well as the parenthesis; if you are simply trying to match a single parenthesis you do not need the brackets. Remember your backslash when using special (reserved) characters in an expression.

Comment: I've found that [(] is equivalent to \( and more readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

> Looking through the Firefox bug database, there have been many regular expression bugs found and categorized loosely as "exponential behavior" bugs. Most of them have been fixed in the newer versions of the browser.

[In this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=539080#c7) there are a couple of comments from Brendan Eich about the issue, and he lists several other bugs (some pretty old).  Another comment there alludes to an "overhaul in regular expression" in Firefox 4, suggesting that many changes occurred as far back as that.